# Flutter: Provider: How to handle model dependencies?

Tags: flutter, architecture, flutter-provider

I'm looking for suggestions on how to handle loading things after login, and combine data from multiple endpoints without mixing too much stuff, specifically the following two things:

### 1) Login flow

After I get a successful login response with `userId`, I need to push `HomeScreen()` and load some initial data, from various providers.

Example:

```
// home_screen.dart

initState() {
  super.initState();
  initializeData();
}

Future <void> initializeData() {

  var authenticationProvider = Provider.of<AuthenticationProvider>(context);
  var accountProvider = Provider.of<AccountProvider>(context);
  
  var albumProvider = Provider.of<AlbumProvider>(context);
  var songProvider = Provider.of<SongProvider>(context);
  
  await accountProvider.loadAccount(authenticationProvider.getLoggedInUser().id);
  await albumProvider.loadAlbums();
  await songProvider.loadSongsForAlbums(albumProvider.getAlbums())
  
}
```

This works, but feels ugly?

### 2) Cleaner data sharing

Imagine the API like this:

api/albums (model contains info about album)

api/albumpurchases (model contains which `albumId` and `userId`)

What would be the best way to get purchased albums of the logged in user?

I can think of 3 different ways, none of which seem good:

1. AlbumProvider having two arrays, `albums[]`, and `purchases[]`, and a method `getAlbumByPurchase (String purchaseId)` or `getPurchaseForAlbum(String albumId)` which then does `.where()` by Id and returns the item.
2. Having `AlbumProvider` and `AlbumPurchaseProvider`, then using `ProxyProvider` to combine the two.
   I'm not sure how exactly would that be implemented, an example would be very appreciated!
3. Adding `purchase` property to an `Album`, then manually mapping it similarly to way #1
   .
   I've used this so far, and it seems great in the beginning but gets very ugly very quick since your subsequent `Album` HTTP responses everywhere would be lacking that `purchase` property, so I either need to get the `purchase` again, or I need to get it an `Album` object with the purchase from `AlbumProvider` based on an Id in response I got.